# Are any ancient team sports (not games or athletics) mentioned in our scriptures?

Tags: scripture, vedas, mahabharata, manuscripts, ramayana

I wish to know if team sports existed in the ancient times. Especially in Ramayan and Mahabharat. By sports I don’t mean swimming, archery etc. I’m looking for something like football and cricket

Please don’t delete the question

Comment: Wrestling or [मल्लयुद्ध](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malla-yuddha) or its variants, seems like a good candidate for a "sport" ?!